# browsers do not offer Java Web Start for .jnlp

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp

Since recently I get support cases where the browser (Firefox, IE11) does not offer Java Web Start for .jnlp files – even after fresh Java installations. The users have to search for javaws.exe on their own.

Did anything change? Maybe with Java 9? We currently recommend Java 9 as we had some trouble with a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8195830) in latest Java 8 (Update 161/162).

Does the Java 9 installer no longer associate JNLP with Java Web Start? Maybe having to do with that [deprecation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html#JDK-8184998)? (I was shocked about it, by the way. No idea how we can distribute our many different clients to thousands of business partners without Java Web Start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Java 9, the file association for Java Web Start no longer exists.  Note that when you download Java from Sun, the latest current version is still version 8, which should still work.

You can alternatively create that association of .jnlp to javaws.exe, even in Java 9 and 10.

As of this year, Java 11 no longer contains the binary javaws.exe at all.